# pyGTK detect all window move events

Tags: python, linux, events, pygtk

I'm trying to capture the configure-event for every window to create a windows 7-esque snap feature. I know there are solutions involving compiz-fusion, but my installation is running within vmware and doesn't have hardware acceleration to run compiz. I figured a simple python script could do what I wanted, but I can't seem to find the right place to bind the configure-event to.

How/to what do you bind the configure-event callback, or is there a different event I need to watch for? I've tried binding it to the screen and the root window using get_root_window() with no luck.

*EDIT2*

Now I can capture all events, the problem is that every event returned is of type GDK_NOTHING, so I can't tell the difference between focus events, move events, close events, etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk, wnck
import inspect

def move_event(e):
    print e.type, e.window
    print inspect.getmembers(e)
    return gtk.gdk.FILTER_CONTINUE

def bind_win(screen, win):
    w = gtk.gdk.window_foreign_new(win.get_xid())
    if w:
        w.set_events(w.get_events() | gtk.gdk.ALL_EVENTS_MASK)
        w.add_filter(move_event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    screen = wnck.screen_get_default()
    screen.connect("window_opened", bind_win)
    gtk.main()
```

One iteration of move_event(e) while dragging a window:

`<enum GDK_NOTHING of type GdkEventType> <gtk.gdk.Window object at 0x7f38f72f8730 (GdkWindow at 0x196ce20)>
[('copy', <built-in method copy of gtk.gdk.Event object at 0x7f3900513d00>), ('free', <built-in method free of gtk.gdk.Event object at 0x7f3900513d00>), ('get_axis', <built-in method get_axis of gtk.gdk.Event object at 0x7f3900513d00>), ('get_coords', <built-in method get_coords of gtk.gdk.Event object at 0x7f3900513d00>), ('get_root_coords', <built-in method get_root_coords of gtk.gdk.Event object at 0x7f3900513d00>), ('get_screen', <built-in method get_screen of gtk.gdk.Event object at 0x7f3900513d00>), ('get_state', <built-in method get_state of gtk.gdk.Event object at 0x7f3900513d00>), ('get_time', <built-in method get_time of gtk.gdk.Event object at 0x7f3900513d00>), ('put', <built-in method put of gtk.gdk.Event object at 0x7f3900513d00>), ('send_client_message', <built-in method send_client_message of gtk.gdk.Event object at 0x7f3900513d00>), ('send_clientmessage_toall', <built-in method send_clientmessage_toall of gtk.gdk.Event object at 0x7f3900513d00>), ('send_event', 1), ('set_screen', <built-in method set_screen of gtk.gdk.Event object at 0x7f3900513d00>), ('type', <enum GDK_NOTHING of type GdkEventType>), ('window', <gtk.gdk.Window object at 0x7f38f72f8730 (GdkWindow at 0x196ce20)>)]`

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I think it might be a gtk bug.

Comment: I've filed a bug here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=722027

Answer (score 1):

A quick search reveals [this](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/gtktutorial/gtkevents/) page, which, though written in C, communicates the basics pretty well (you'll have to `grep` it to find for "Moving Window")

The configure-event is binded to your application's window.

To do what you're going to want to do, you'll also have to find out the screen size, which resides in gtk.gdk.screen, documented [here](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkscreen.html).

Comment: Thanks for the links, I was looking for a way to listen for **all** configure events on all existing and future windows. Your method applies only when creating a new window.

Comment: I though you were talking within you own app. You can always fork e16 :)